# Awk substring doesnt yield expected result

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I've a file whose content is below:

```
C2:0301,353458082243570,353458082243580,0;
C2:0301,353458082462440,353458082462450,0;
C2:0301,353458082069130,353458082069140,0;
C2:0301,353458082246230,353458082246240,0;
C2:0301,353458082559320,353458082559330,0;
C2:0301,353458080153530,353458080153540,0;
C2:0301,353458082462670,353458082462680,0;
C2:0301,353458081943950,353458081943960,0;
C2:0301,353458081719070,353458081719080,0;
C2:0301,353458081392470,353458081392490,0;
```

`Field 2 and Field 3` (considering `,` as separator), contains `15 digit IMEI number` `ranges` and `not` individual `IMEI numbers`. Usual format of `IMEI` is `8-digits(TAC)+6-digits(Serial number)+0(padded)`. The `6 digits(Serial number)` part in the `IMEI` defines the start and end range, everything else remaining same. So in order to find individual `IMEIs` in the ranges (which is exactly what I want), I need a `unary increment loop` from `6 digits(Serial number)` from the `starting IMEI number` `in Field-2` till `6 digits(Serial number)` from the `ending IMEI number` `in Field-3`. I am using the below `AWK` script:

```
awk -F"," '{v = substr($2,9,6); t = substr($3,9,6); while(v <= t) printf "%s%0"6"s%s,%s\n", substr($3,1,8),v++,substr($3,15,2),$4;}' TEMP.OUT.merge_range_part1_21
```

It gives me the below result:

```
353458082243570,0
353458082243580,0
353458082462440,0
353458082462450,0
353458082069130,0
353458082069140,0
353458082246230,0
353458082246240,0
353458082559320,0
353458082559330,0
353458080153530,0
353458082462670,0
353458082462680,0
353458081943950,0
353458081943960,0
353458081719070,0
353458081719080,0
353458081392470,0
353458081392480,0
353458081392490,0
```

The above is as expected except for the below line in the `result`:

```
 353458080153530,0
```

The `result` is actually from the below line in the `input file`:

```
 C2:0301,353458080153530,353458080153540,0;
```

But the `expected output` for the above line in `input file` is:

```
  353458080153530,0
  353458080153540,0
```

I need to know whats going wrong in my script.

Comment: not only that one case, but also last 3 lines of your input: `353458081392470,0
353458081392480,0
353458081392490,0` - this `353458081392480,0` should not be there

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest That is fine. Basically the increment has to happen on `substr($2,9,6)`. In this case `139247` is increasing till `139249` hence I have `353458081392470,0 353458081392480,0 353458081392490,0` and that is exactly what I expect. My problem is my script is not handling the case where I have leading zero. For example for the problematic case above `substr($2,9,6)` is `015353`. it should increment till `015354` and I should have both `353458080153530,0` and `353458080153540,0`. That is not happening

Comment: Ignore my answer as it won't work on a second iteration of the while loop

Comment: Setting v=y at the end of the statement should make it work on additional increments.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do, never mind what might be wrong with it. Can you simplify your example and clarify your requirements?

Comment: @EdMorton I have edited my question now, and have tried to clarify my requirement as much as I could. Let me know if the description makes sense now as far as what I'm expecting from my script.

Comment: @EdMorton My script is not handling the case where the `6-digit Serial Number` in my `15-digit IMEI number` has `leading 0s`. That's the only difference I find from the successful cases and the only failure case explained in my Question body. Any suggestions to improve my script so that the failed scenario is considered ?

Comment: `NOTE:` `The 6 digit serial number` is basically any `6 digit number` in the range `000000 - 999999`. So I have to consider all these scenarios.

Comment: SO you just want to print the numbers in the range between the serial numbers in the 2nd and third field on each line? Then why give us 10 lines of input and dozens of lines of output to have to wade through instead of just the 2 or 3 lines of input that demonstrate your problem? Right now we can't see the wood for the trees...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your script is you start with 2 string variables, v and t, (typed as strings since they are the result of a string operation, substr()) and then convert one to a number with `v++` which would strip leading zeros but then you're doing a string comparison with `v <= t` since a string (t) compared to a number or string or numeric string is always a string comparison. Yes you can add zero to each of the variables to force a numeric comparison but IMHO this is more like what you're really trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; re="(.{8})(.{6})(.*)" }
{
    match($2,re,beg)
    match($3,re,end)
    for (i=beg[2]; i<=end[2]; i++) {
        printf "%s%06d%s\n", end[1], i, end[3]
    }
}

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
353458082243570
353458082243580
353458082462440
353458082462450
353458082069130
353458082069140
353458082246230
353458082246240
353458082559320
353458082559330
353458080153530
353458080153540
353458082462670
353458082462680
353458081943950
353458081943960
353458081719070
353458081719080
353458081392470
353458081392480
353458081392490
```

and when done with appropriate variables like that no conversion is necessary. Note also that with the above you don't need to repeatedly state the same or relative numbers to extract the part of the strings you care about, you just state the number of characters to skip (8) and the number to select (6) once. The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match().

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the `while(v <= t)` part of the script. I believe with `leading 0s` the match was not happening properly. So I ensured that they are `casted into int` while doing the comparison in the while loop. The AWK documentation says you can cast a value to int by using `value+0`. So my `while(v <= t)` in the `awk` script needed to change to `while(v+0 <= t+0)` . So the below AWK script:

```
 awk -F"," '{v = substr($2,9,6); t = substr($3,9,6); while(v <= t) printf "%s%0"6"s%s,%s\n", substr($3,1,8),v++,substr($3,15,2),$4;}' TEMP.OUT.merge_range_part1_21
```

was changed to :

```
awk -F"," '{v = substr($2,9,6); t = substr($3,9,6); while(v+0 <= t+0) printf "%s%0"6"s%s,%s\n", substr($3,1,8),v++,substr($3,15,2),$4;}' TEMP.OUT.merge_range_part1_21
```

That only change got me the expected value for the failure case. For example this in my `input file`:

```
C2:0301,353458080153530,353458080153540,0;
```

Now gives me individual IMEIs as :

```
353458080153530,0
353458080153540,0
```

Comment: For efficiency instead of adding zero every time you compare the variables you should just be adding zero when you init them `v = substr($2,9,6)+0; t = substr($3,9,6)+0`, nor should you be calling substr() multiple times within the loop to get the same substrings each time. And why write `printf "..%0"6"s..\n"` instead of just `printf "..%06s..\n"`?

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the inputs. I'll incorporate these.

Answer (score -1):

Use an if statement that checks for leading zeros in variable v setting y accordingly:

```
awk -F"," '{v = substr($2,9,6); t = substr($3,9,6); while(v <= t) { if (substr(v,1,1)=="0") { v++;y="0"v } else { v++;y=v } ;printf %s%0"6"s%s,%s\n", substr($3,1,8),y,substr($3,15,2),$4;v=y } }' TEMP.OUT.merge_range_part1_21
```

Make sure that the while condition is contained in braces and also that v is incremented WITHIN the if conditions.

Set v=y at the end of the statement to allow this to work on additional increments.

Comment: Does this even work ? It gives me whole lot of errors. Also your code handles only 1 `0`. I'm looking for a generalized code for any number of leading 0s. So basically `substr($2,9,6)` always have to be six digits. If there is a case say `000153` to `000156`, that should also be handled

Comment: It worked on the sample data you gavebut hasn't taken account of multiple zeros.